# How can I display my video bitrate in MBps using MediaInfo on the command line with --Inform

Tags: bash, awk, mediainfo

I have this command:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%CodecID% %BitRate/String% %Height%p" ./filename.mp4
```

which displays:

```
avc1 882 kb/s 720p
```

but I would like it to display in MBps instead, with a max of one decimal place, like 1.1 MBps.

can I do this out of the box without using bash and `numfmt`? If I do need `numfmt`, how could I use that?

Comment: Currently there is no internal formatting possibility for bitrate, and there is also no possibility to display a byterate (MB/s is not a bitrate ;-) ), in MediaInfo. Planned, but currently not a priority. Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `/String` to get bit rate in bps and append:

```
| awk '{$2=sprintf("%.1f Mbps",$2/1024/1024)}1'
```